# Can I run a bsc full node with this configuration?

Tags: blockchain, bsc, binance

I would like to run a bsc full node, as this is this takes time and is also my first time, could you please tell me if this configuration is enough:

```
1x Intel Xeon E5 1650
6 Cores / 12 Threads - 3,2 GHz
64 GB RAM
2 x 1TB SSD
1 Gbit/s Bandwidth
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see the minimum requirements on this [page](https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/developer/fullnode.html).

Answer (score 0):

The official requirement is 8 cores. However some people having success with 4 cores as well. My first node had 48 cores and 128 gib memory which was an overkill. Btw I went with 8TB storage as the disk went full at 6.4TB at my first setup attempt.